# User of "rename -p/--mkpath--make-dirs

Tags: rename, path

I try to understand the syntax of the rename command option switch "-p/--mkpath--make-dirs".

I am searching now the web for some time, but this option does not seem to be very common. I cannot not find a single example.

From the manual:

> Create any non-existent directories in the target path. This is
> very handy if you want to scatter a pile of files into
> subdirectories based on some part of their name (eg. the first two
> letters or the extension): you don't need to make all necessary
> directories beforehand, just tell "rename" to create them as
> necessary.

This is exactly what I would like to do. Can somebody give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much "syntax" to the option, you just use it like most options:

```
% touch a-b-c-d
% tree
.
└── a-b-c-d

0 directories, 1 file
% rename -pn 's:-:/:g' a-b-c-d
'a-b-c-d' would be renamed to 'a/b/c/d'
% rename -p 's:-:/:g' a-b-c-d
% tree -F
.
└── a/
    └── b/
        └── c/
            └── d

3 directories, 1 file
```

Comment: Which `rename` is this? Perl or util? Your substitution operator suggests perl, but I don't see that option in mine. In any of mine, actually.

Comment: @terdon I'm on macOS right now, and got it from brew: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rename Turns out it's *a* Perl one from http://plasmasturm.org/ (see http://plasmasturm.org/log/rename1601/, http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/ and http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) (but not *the* Perl one, I suppose)

Comment: Wow, the latest LTS version of Ubuntu (22.04) doesn't have this version of rename :( And that site doesn't work anymore.

Comment: ...but you can get the perl script directly from here: https://github.com/ap/rename/blob/master/rename